# how to use mixin when the theme overrides the js component

Tags: magento2.3, mixins

I'm experiencing the following issue.

I have a theme which overrides the swatch renderer in

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Name/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js
```

I also have a module which adds a mixin for `Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js`

However the function I'm wrapping is never executed.

```
 /*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
 /*global alert*/
 define([
'jquery',
'mage/utils/wrapper'
 ], function ($, wrapper) {
'use strict';

return function (targetModule) {
    var updatePrice = targetModule.prototype._UpdatePrice;
    targetModule.prototype.dynamic = {};
    var updatePriceWrapper = wrapper.wrap(updatePrice, function (original) {
        // console.log('execute mixin');
        return original();
    });

    targetModule.prototype._UpdatePrice = updatePriceWrapper;
    return targetModule;

};
});
```

This is the theme's override

https://pastebin.com/xch5jwmH

Any ideas why I can't wrap the function? I also tried wrapping other functions of the component but it still never executes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following instead of wrapper:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer'
], function($) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget('vendor.SwatchRenderer', $.mage.SwatchRenderer, {
        _UpdatePrice: function () {
            console.log('mixin');
            return this._super();
        }
    });

    return $.vendor.SwatchRenderer;
});
```

Also make sure that you added correct dependency to your `module.xml`:

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ModuleName">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Swatches"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```